# Selenium Browser Drivers can't be configured through System Property when referenced through Class Objects

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Selenium Browser Drivers can't be configured through System Property when referenced through Class Objects.

---

## Environment Details

**`Selenium`: 3.5.0**

**`GeckoDriver`: 0.18.0**

**`Mozilla Firefox`: 55.0.2**

**`OS`: Windows 8 Pro**

---

### Usecase

When trying to set the System Property through a class method Selenium is unable to find the webdriver executable and throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException` with error message as:

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

---

### Code Block:

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q45756729_PageTitle 
{
    WebDriver driver;
    public void title()
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    String titleofthepage=driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(titleofthepage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Q45756729_PageTitle obj1=new Q45756729_PageTitle();
        obj1.title(); 
    }
}
```

---

### Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:750)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at demo.Q45756729_PageTitle.tite(Q45756729_PageTitle.java:12)
    at demo.Q45756729_PageTitle.main(Q45756729_PageTitle.java:21)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime this happens:)-

Replace this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
```

with

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: U can also set path value for your geckodriver.exe and no need to pass the path

Answer (score 0):

Use `gecko.driver` in place of `Firefox.driver` like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:/Gecko/geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
```

need to be replaced by

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");`

as the driver exe has been replaced by gecko however classname is still FirefoxDriver.